# Getting the java script array elements into the html form as a input field value?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am having 6 bootstrap cards where the card details are id,content. Onclick of every card I am getting the ids of clicked card into the array from the local storage now I want to send that ids to the html form as value for input field 
My html code is:

```
<body onload = "sample(),issample()">

<div class="form-group" >
  <input type="text" name="goal" id="goal" value=" ">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="password2">Password</label>
  <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" required>
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Register" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">
```

My JS code is:

```
var goal = []
function getGoal(id, content) {
  if (goal.length > 0) {
     var data = { id: id, content: $("#cont_" + id).text() }
     var x = JSON.stringify(data)
     var index = goal.indexOf(x)
     if (index == -1) {
       goal.push(x)
     }
     else {
      goal.splice(index, 1)
     }
  }
  else {
    var data = { id: id, content: $("#cont_" + id).text() }
    var x = JSON.stringify(data)
    goal.push(x)
  }
  localStorage.setItem("goal", JSON.stringify(goal))
  // To get all ids
  var storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("goal"))
  var goalIds = []
  if (storedNames)
   storedNames.forEach(element => {
   element = JSON.parse(element)
   goalIds.push(element.id)
  });
  console.log(goalIds)
}
 function issample(){
 $("#goal").val(goalIds);
 }
```

I am getting error as goalIds not defined but the goalIds array is getting the ids but that ids are not getting in the form as a value

Comment: You declared `goalIds` in `getGoal` function and it is only available in the function unless you place the array somewhere else (like in `window` scope)

Comment: @ Thum so now how can I access the goalids in another function can you say me the code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared `goalIds` in `getGoal` function and it is only accessible in that function. If you need to use the array in somewhere else then you can declare it outside the function

```
var goal = [];
var goalIds = [];
function getGoal(id, content){
    ...code here

    goalIds = [];

    if (storedNames)
        storedNames.forEach(element => {
            element = JSON.parse(element)
            goalIds.push(element.id)
        });
    console.log(goalIds)

    // If you need to set the value for every `getGoal` call
    issample();
}

function issample(){
    $("#goal").val(goalIds);
}
```

Comment: @ Thum when I wrote your code it is getting as duplicated ids are coming into the array when I click the cards

Comment: You can reset the `goalIds` to `[]` in `getGoal`

Comment: @ Thum can you say with an example?

Comment: Updated the answer